# how to update a cell of a spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following a dataFrame on which I'm trying to update a cell depending on some conditions (like sql update where..)
for example, let's say  I have the following data Frame :

```
+-------+-------+
|datas  |isExist|
+-------+-------+
|   AA  |   x   |
|   BB  |   x   |
|   CC  |   O   |
|   CC  |   O   |
|   DD  |   O   |
|   AA  |   x   |
|   AA  |   x   |
|   AA  |   O   |
|   AA  |   O   |
+-------+-------+
```

How could I update the values to ***X*** when datas=AA and isExist is O, here is the expected output :

```
+-------+-------+
|IPCOPE2|IPROPE2|
+-------+-------+
|   AA  |   x   |
|   BB  |   x   |
|   CC  |   O   |
|   CC  |   O   |
|   DD  |   O   |
|   AA  |   x   |
|   AA  |   x   |
|   AA  |   X   |
|   AA  |   X   |
+-------+-------+
```

I could do a filter, then union, but I think its not the best solution, 
I could also use the **when**, but in this case I had create a new line containing the same values except for the isExist column, in that example is an acceptable solution, but what if I have 20 column !!

Comment: Spark distributed datasets like  DataFrame or RDD´s are immutable. Your transformation will create another DataFrame representation.

Comment: yeah I know its not a problem, in fact I want a new dataFrame that will contains the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new column using `withColumn` (either putting original or updated value) and then drop `isExist` column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you do not want to use `when` for it seems to be exactly what you need. The `withColumn` method, when used with an existing column name will simply replace the column by the new value:

```scala
df.withColumn("isExist",
      when('datas === "AA" && 'isExist === "O", "X").otherwise('isExist))
  .show()
+-----+-------+
|datas|isExist|
+-----+-------+
|   AA|      x|
|   BB|      x|
|   CC|      O|
|   CC|      O|
|   DD|      O|
|   AA|      x|
|   AA|      x|
|   AA|      X|
|   AA|      X|
+-----+-------+
```

Then you can use `withColumnRenamed` to change the names of your columns. (e.g. `df.withColumnRenamed("datas", "IPCOPE2")`)

Comment: when return a column , therefore, each time I have to add a column and drop it again, ,that is what I'm doing for now, as suggested by @Vladislav Varslavans, however, I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: for example is there, a specific method for doing that, for example, is it possible to execute sql like, commands